# How is optional assignment constexpr in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++20, constexpr

To the internal content of an optional, doesn't the optional require placement new in order to reconstruct the internal in place storage or union? Is there some new feature like placement new in C++ 20 that allows for constexpr assignment of std::optional?

```
template< class U = T >
optional& operator=( U&& value );
(since C++17)
(until C++20)
template< class U = T >
constexpr optional& operator=( U&& value );
(since C++20)
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at  It's not clear to me, though, how the `T*` is obtained to pass in in a constexpr context. There is further information in [the proposal](https://wg21.link/P2231R1).

Comment: Ah I think the T* comes from a constexpr union type. But yes I geuss this is what they are using to constexpr construct great! Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> To the internal content of an optional, doesn't the optional require placement new in order to reconstruct the internal in place storage or union?

For assignment, yes it does.

But while we still cannot do *actual* placement new during constexpr time, we did get a workaround for its absence: [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) (from [P0784](https://wg21.link/p0784)). This is a very limited form of placement new, but it's enough to get `optional` assignment working.

The other change was that we also needed to be able to actually change the active member of a union - since it wouldn't matter if we could construct the new object if we couldn't actually switch. That also happened in C++20 ([P1330](https://wg21.link/p1330)).

Put those together, and you get a functional implementation of optional assignment: [P2231](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2231r1.html). An abbreviated implementation would look like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct optional {
    union {
        T value;
        char empty;
    };
    bool has_value;

    constexpr optional& operator=(T const& rhs) {
        if (has_value) {
            value = rhs;
        } else {
            // basically ::new (&value) T(rhs);
            // except blessed for constexpr usage
            std::construct_at(&value, rhs); 
        }
        has_value = true;
        return *this;
    }
};
```